# Naming an object like a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to name an object like the value of a variable, but I simply don't know how to do it. Var = Obj() will just name the object like the variable, but not like the value.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  Do you mean that you have, say, a variable `foo = "bar"` and you want to use `foo` to name a variable `bar`?  If so, [that's a bad idea](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: When I have a class named foo, and a variable bar, I want to create an instance of foo with the value of bar as the name.

Comment: @Jeyex like jwodder said, that's a bad idea. You want to [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Ned Batchelder is a very smart person, I'd listen to him :)

Comment: Basically, the quick answer is to use a dict (or a defaultdict, or some other similar data structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it, createting variables dynamically looks like a bad idea. Sorry for the dumb question, that's what happens when you try to teach yourself programming. But thank you for the quick responses